# How can I edit some data using form view and some data remains uneditable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, formview

I have this code in my aspx.cs page. In my database, I have columns `Username`, `Firstname`, `Lastname`, `Email`, `Password`,  `CustomerType`, `DeliveryAddress`, `Zipcode` and `Contact number`.

What I want to do is that the username and customer type remains uneditable and the others can be edited by the user.

**aspx.cs**

```
    protected void fvClientProfile_ItemUpdating(object sender, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

        DataKey key = fvClientProfile.DataKey;
        TextBox txtFN = (TextBox)fvClientProfile.FindControl("txtFN");
        TextBox txtLN = (TextBox)fvClientProfile.FindControl("txtLN");
        TextBox txtAddress = (TextBox)fvClientProfile.FindControl("txtAddress");
        TextBox txtEmail = (TextBox)fvClientProfile.FindControl("txtEmail");
        TextBox txtContact = (TextBox)fvClientProfile.FindControl("txtContact");

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("", conn);

        conn.Open();

        da.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand( "UPDATE UserData SET FirstName ='" + txtFN.Text + "',LastName ='" + txtLN.Text + "',Address ='" + txtAddress.Text + "',Email ='" + txtEmail.Text + "',Contact='"+ txtContact.Text+"'  WHERE ID='" + key.Value.ToString() + "'");

        da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Response.Write("Record updated successfully");
        bindgrid();
        conn.Close();
    }

    protected void fvClientProfile_ModeChanging(object sender, FormViewModeEventArgs e)
    {
        fvClientProfile.ChangeMode(e.NewMode);
        bindgrid();

        if (e.NewMode == FormViewMode.Edit)
        {
            fvClientProfile.AllowPaging = false;
        }
        else
        {
            fvClientProfile.AllowPaging = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

Use EditItemTemplate for those column you want to edit. For example:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
                  <table>


                    <tr><td align="right"><b>First Name:</b></td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName2"
                                         Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'
                                         RunAt="Server" /></td></tr>

                    <tr><td align="right"><b>Last Name:</b></td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName2"
                                         Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>'
                                         RunAt="Server" /></td></tr>                                 
                    <tr>
                      <td colspan="2">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton"
                                        Text="Update"
                                        CommandName="Update"
                                        RunAt="server"/>
                          &nbsp;
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="CancelUpdateButton"
                                        Text="Cancel"
                                        CommandName="Cancel"
                                        RunAt="server"/>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>                
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: yes i have that sir. when i try to run it, it gives me "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." thank you for the fast response sir

Comment: You are trying to use a reference variable whose value is Nothing/null. When the value is Nothing/null for the reference variable, that means it is not actually holding a reference to an instance of any object that exists on the heap. Then this exception will arise. Use break point and debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem. Thank you @Litisqe Kumar for giving me a good idea on what is the problem.

Given the answer above wherein you should put the editable fields inside the `<EditTemplate>`, here is the code behind.

```
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConn"].ConnectionString;
    SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
    DataTable dt;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["New"] != null)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                bindgrid();
            }
        }
    }
    private void bindgrid()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        dt = new DataTable();
        com.Connection = conn;
        com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE Username ='" + Session["New"] + "'";
        sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        sqlda.Fill(dt);
        EmployeeFormView.DataSource = dt;
        EmployeeFormView.DataBind();

    }

    protected void EmployeeFormView_ItemUpdating(object sender, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

        DataKey key = EmployeeFormView.DataKey;
        TextBox txtFirstName = (TextBox)EmployeeFormView.FindControl("txtFirstName2");
        TextBox txtLastName = (TextBox)EmployeeFormView.FindControl("txtLastName2");
        TextBox txtPass = (TextBox)EmployeeFormView.FindControl("txtPassword2");
        TextBox txtAddress = (TextBox)EmployeeFormView.FindControl("txtAddress2");
        TextBox txtZip = (TextBox)EmployeeFormView.FindControl("txtZip2");
        TextBox txtContact = (TextBox)EmployeeFormView.FindControl("txtContact2");

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        com.Connection = conn;
        com.CommandText = "UPDATE UserData SET FirstName ='" + txtFirstName.Text + "',LastName ='" + txtLastName.Text + "',DeliveryAddress ='" + txtAddress.Text + "', Zip ='"+txtZip.Text+ "',Password ='"+ txtPass.Text+"',ContactNumber ='" + txtContact.Text + "'   WHERE ID ='" + key.Value.ToString() + "'";
        conn.Open();
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Write("Record updated successfully");
        bindgrid();
        conn.Close();
    }
    protected void EmployeeFormView_ModeChanging(object sender, FormViewModeEventArgs e)
    {
        EmployeeFormView.ChangeMode(e.NewMode);
        bindgrid();
        if (e.NewMode == FormViewMode.Edit)
        {
            EmployeeFormView.AllowPaging = false;
        }
        else
        {
            EmployeeFormView.AllowPaging = true;
        }
    }

    protected void EmployeeFormView_ItemUpdated(object sender, FormViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        EmployeeFormView.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.ReadOnly);
    }
```